# Multiple file mask for WinSCP Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm rebuilding the FTP portion of a system monitor app, has to be able to download any file that is:

- .csv
- .xlsx
- .xls

and when I try to setup that mask, its returning 0 files, but if I pick just one of them, it works perfectly.

```
string FileMask = "*.csv; *.xlsx; *.xls";

var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpHost"],
    UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpUsr"],
    Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpPwd"],
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SshHostKeyFingerprint"]
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    List<string> files =
        session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/", FileMask, EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories)
        .Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName)
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine($"Found {files.Count} files");
}
```

I've tried a couple things and nothing is working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mask` argument of `Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles#mask) is Windows wildcard. There's no way to match multiple extensions with Windows wildcard.

But you can filter the files yourself. For example using a regular expression:

```
Regex mask = new Regex(@"\.(csv|xls|xlsx)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
List <string> files =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/", null, EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fileInfo => mask.Match(fileInfo.Name).Success)
    .Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: awesome that's what I needed, is there a way to have it ignore a certain sub folder? I noticed it looks in a sub folder used as a general packrat folder that I'd need to ignore.

Comment: The same way. Use `Where` extension method.